# Calling function in window,onload vs in body

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, global-variables

I have the following HTML. It draws a Colorado state flag, but only if I move the lines that are in the `window.onload()` function into the `drawLogo()` function, so I think the trouble is not that `drawLogo()` doesn't get called, but that the global `canvas, ctx, x,` and `y` are somehown not really global. I want to put in other functions that do other things in this same canvas, so that is why I want the `canvas, ctx, x,` and `y` to be global.

I know `window.onload()` gets executed, because I can also get it to draw the flag by putting the call to `drawLogo()` inside `window.onload()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Logo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas;
var ctx;
var x;
var y;

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('logo');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    x = canvas.width;
    y = canvas.height; 
};

var drawLogo = function() {   
    var radius = 23;
    var counterClockwise = false;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(3, 20, 75, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.8)';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    //ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.rect(3, y-60, 75, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.8)';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(40, 70, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'Yellow';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(40, 70, 30, 2.15 * Math.PI, 3.85 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#cc3333';
    ctx.lineWidth = 18;
    ctx.stroke();

};

</script>

</head>
<body>
     <div>
       <canvas id="logo" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         drawLogo();
        </script>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload` is called when the entire page is loaded, this means CSS, JS files, Fonts, images and almost everything is downloaded.

Your `drawLogo` function instead is executed when the `script` tag is evaluated while loading the page.

What is happening then is that the `drawLogo` function is called before you populate the global variables.

A simple solution would be to put your `drawLogo` function inside the `window.onload` function.
I 'd also suggest to change the `onload` event with a quicker `onready` in your case, but it is a minor thing.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm trying to make `drawLogo()` into a portable stand alone .js file, so is there a way to execute `drawLogo()` within the body of the html, but after `window.onload()` (or `window.onready()`?) has had a chance to execute?

Comment: It's not strictly asked in your question, but the idea for doing that is to wrap your functions in a module, then at the bottom of the module listen for the `onload` event.

Comment: Bare in mind that the user that import your js file might change the `onload` callback and in that case the trick above won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, I've now managed to wrap my head around it and it's all working exactly like I thought it should.